# Filter DataFrame Pandas Datatime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a forcast of 24 months in my Dataframe, how can I filter the date to 12 months

I know how to filter by a fixed date.

But my dates are always extended by one month. So I need a variable filter.

My solution should be to filter 12 months from the current month on.

Thanks a lot

Comment: dtype of date is already datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = df[df['Date_column_name'] >= (date.today() + relativedelta(months=+12))]
```

Hope it helps...